# Grouping a list of objects by their attribute threshold into subgroups

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I were to have a list as such, how could it be grouped by a value threshold?

With a maximum grouping threshold of 5, the grouping would work as follows:

```
[1, 2, 4, 7, 10, 20, 100, 101] -> [[1, 2, 4], [7, 10], [20], [100, 101]]
```

Would this be possible with `itertools.groupby`?

Comment: Your question is not specific enough ... how should `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]` be grouped? `[[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7]]`?

Comment: No, it would be grouped by elements 1-5, 6-10, 11-15, 16-20, 21-25, etc. which would produce [[1, 2, 4], [7, 10], [20], [100, 101]]

Comment: Your example is not consistent. The grouping you wrote would produce [[1, 2, 4], [7, 10], [20], [100], [101]]. 100 and 101 would be different groups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go. First the more readable multi-line version:

```
import itertools

numbers = [1, 2, 4, 7, 10, 20, 100, 101]

group_iterator = itertools.groupby(numbers, lambda num: num//5)

numbers_groups = []
for _, group in group_iterator:
    numbers_groups.append(list(group))

print(numbers_groups)
```

```
[[1, 2, 4], [7], [10], [20], [100, 101]]
```

Or the one-liner:

```
import itertools

numbers = [1, 2, 4, 7, 10, 20, 100, 101]

numbers_groups = [list(group) for _, group in itertools.groupby(numbers, lambda num: num//5)]
print(numbers_groups)
```

```
[[1, 2, 4], [7], [10], [20], [100, 101]]
```

The way this works is that `itertools.groupby` takes a key-generating function as input. If you have this function be `num//5`, the numbers 0-4 will generate the key '0', the number 5-9 will generate '1', 10-14 will generate '2', etc.