# Grouping & subgrouping a list of objects based on the object attributes

Tags: python, opencv

I'm working on an OpenCV problem that deals with many lines from a Hough Line Detector. I am attempting to reduce the number of lines by joining overlapping lines together, based on slope, y-intercept, and % overlap.

Just for some background. Here is the image with Hough lines pasted on:[image]

```
hough = cv.HoughLinesP(can, h_rho, h_theta, h_threshold, minLineLength=h_min_line_length, maxLineGap=h_max_line_gap)  # Hough Line Detection
h1 = hough.squeeze() # Output "h1" is an array containing endpoints of detected line segments
```

From this code, I obtain a list of lines that are each a 1x4 NumPy array containing [x1 y1 x2 y2] coordinates.

I then created a class called Line that denotes its coordinates, slope, and y-intercept

```
class Line:
    def __init__(self, x1, y1, x2, y2) -> None:
        self.x1 = x1
        self.y1 = y1
        self.x2 = x2
        self.y2 = y2
        
        if ((x2-x1) != 0): # IF it is NOT vertical
            self.m = (y2-y1) / (x2-x1)
            self.b = y2 - self.m*x2
        else: # IF it is vertical
            self.m = 999
            self.b = 999 # set up as 999 as an identifier & to not have to deal with NoneType
```

Iterated over the list and converted every np array to an instance of this class:

```
l1 = []
for i,line in enumerate(h1):
    x1,y1,x2,y2 = np.ravel(line,"C")
    l = Line(x1,y1,x2,y2)
    l1.append(l)
```

So now I have a list of instances of this class 'Line' that each hold an attribute 'm' & 'b'.

So my plan now is to first sort based on the attribute 'm':

```
# Sort a list of instances based on the property slope, 'm'
l1.sort(key=operator.attrgetter('m'))
```

So now my list of instances is sorted in ascending order of the value of 'm'.

I want to now create a sub-list within this list of instances based on a threshold value for 'm'. I have a sorted list of instances [<instance.Line object ...1>, <... 2>, <... 3>, etc] with its associated slopes & intercepts where the corresponding slopes would look something like [-85, -50, -50, -1.125, -0.75, -0.679, -0.12, -0.13, -0.16, 25, 27,..., 999, 999]. With a threshold value of say 2, I would like to output a grouped list of instances [ [1], [2, 3], [4 5 6], [7 8 9], [10 11], ..., [850 851] ] which correspond to the slopes looking like [ [-85], [-50, -50], [-1.125, -0.75, -0.679], [-0.12, -0.13, -0.16], [25, 27], ..., [999, 999] ].

(Just for clarity, if the threshold was 5 and the list was [-5 -4 -3 -2 -1 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 ], it should output [ [-5 -4 -3 -2 -1], [0 1 2 3 4], [5 6 7 8 9], [10 11] ] )

I saw this and adapted it to a list of instances.
[Grouping a list of objects by their attribute threshold into subgroups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57015108/grouping-a-list-of-objects-by-their-attribute-threshold-into-subgroups)

```
# Sub-group the list based on similarity in slope, 'm' (the sub-grouping order can be switched to optimize speed based on the standard deviation of the 'm' & 'b')
    l2 = [list(group) for _, group in itertools.groupby(l1, lambda num: num.m//2)]
```

However, it sub-groups as it crosses a 0 value. meaning that it will not sub-group correctly.

My plan for next steps would be to now sub-group within each sub-group based on the attribute 'b' using a similar method. Squeeze out the previous sub-grouping such that now it is simply a list of lines that are grouped by similarity in both 'm' & 'b'. I will then iterate over each group and define a %overlap with the other lines in the group, and then decide on how to delete the lines that are completely enveloped by another line.

Is there perhaps a simpler way to approach this problem?

Comment: Based on the post you linked, I guess (but didn't try) using `lambda x:x.m//2` as a grouping key might work.

Comment: There is a case failure with this method: it sub-groups when crossing 0. i.e. [-1.125, -1, -0.5, 0, 0.1, 0.3] with a threshold of 2 does not output [[-1.125 -1 -0.5 0 0.1], [0.3]], it outputs [[-1.125 -1 -0.5], [0 0.1 0.3]].

Comment: That's predictable (and existed in the answer you linked): these grouping functions use absolute ranges; that said, I think any method will have side effects (imagine regularly spaced values: you'll always have to draw the line somewhere, leaving out a value that's near the previous one).

Comment: Hmmm, that makes it difficult as I do have to group horizontal lines (the majority of the lines) together to de-noise. Are there any functions I might be able to use or related ones that I could look at documentation for? Perhaps I could play with the grouping key?

Comment: As I said, you have to draw a line somewhere, can you get to choose where to draw it: the function I submitted roughly separates values into ranges [-4, -2], [-2,0], [0,2] ... ; but if you prefer [-3,-1] [-1,1] [1,3] ..., just use `lambda x:(x.m + 1)//2`